# filtering making subqueries

Tags: laravel, eloquent, subquery, filtering

I'm on a Laravel project and I'm trying to do a filter:

I have the following tables: pubs, tapps, pub_tapps(pub_id, tapp_id)

I would like to filter an item (pubs, in this case) by some characteristics that are stored in a separate table (tapps, in this case), and both are related by pub_tapps.

An array of chosen tapps id's is given to me, then I want to query on pub_tapps to know the pub_id's that satisfy the conditions.

For example, I'm trying to filter by WIFI (tapp_id=5) and CreditCard (tapp_id=16). If we're strict the result must be pub_id=57 (tapp_id=5,8), if not pub_id=57 and pub_id=16 (tapp_id=5,7,8).

Any ideas to do something like this?Note that I'm triying to filter with different values of a sema field :S

Thanks a lot for your attention.

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: you want to get the `pub_id` after providing `tapp_id`?

Comment: I'd like to get the pub_id after giving the tapp_id's and this what I tried, but it doesn't give me fine results public function pubsFilteredByTapps(FilteredTappsPubsRequest $tapps_chosen, PubTapp $pubTapp)
    {
        $tapps_chosen = is_string($tapps_chosen) ?
            explode(',', str_replace('"', '', $tapps_chosen)) : $tapps_chosen;

        $pubs_tapps = PubTapp::whereIn('tapp_id', $tapps_chosen)->get()->pluck('pub_id');
        $pubs_selected = Pub::whereIn('id', $pubs_tapps)->get();

        return $this->response(PubProfileResource::collection($pubs_selected));
    }

Comment: I think I could do it if someone can help me to obtain [5, 8] from this {"tapps": "5,8"}, thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as long you An array of chosen tapps $ids

choose tapps that satisfy your conditions

```
$tapIds = Tapps::whereIn('id',$ids)->where('condition',true)->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

then get The Ids of the pubs in the connected Table

```
$pubIds = PubTapps::whereIn('tapp_id',$tapIds)->pluck('pub_id')->toArray();
```

then get the pubs

```
$Pubs = Pubs::whereIn('id',$pubIds)->get();
```

Comment: thanks for your ansewr, but can you explain this: ->where('condition',true)? im having some errors testing

Comment: it's the conditions you want , like Sudent::where('gender','male')->get();
you understand me ?

Comment: @BerTsacianegudelTepuy Like that 
$tapIds = Tapps::whereIn('id',$ids)->where('WIFI',1)->pluck('id')->toArray();
or  
Tapps::whereIn('id',$ids)->where('CreditCard',1)->pluck('id')->toArray();

if you want to do more than one condition like that
Tapps::whereIn('id',$ids)->where('WIFI',1)->where('CreditCard',1)->pluck('id')->toArray();

you got it ?

Comment: oh thanks, but I would  like to do it dinamically...using a foreach how can we insert those  ->where('condition',true)?

Comment: using the get/post requests 

Tapps::whereIn('id',$ids)->where('WIFI',$request['wifi'])->where('CreditCard',$request['credit_card'])->pluck('id')->toArray();

Answer (score 0):

[Many to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

```
class Pubbs extends Model
{
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function tapps()
    {
        //All but the first argument here are optional so long as you follow Laravel naming conventions
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tapps::class, 'pub_tapps', 'pub_id', 'tapp_id', 'id', 'id');
    }
}
```

---

[whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

```
$tappIds = [5, 16];
$strictMode = true;
$pubs = app(App\Models\Pubbs::class)->whereHas('tapps', function (Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query) use ($tappIds, $strictMode) {
    $tappKey = $query->getModel()->getKeyName();
    if (!$strictMode) {
        return $query->whereIn($tappKey, $tappIds);
    }
    foreach ($tappIds as $tappId) {
        $query->where($tappKey, $tappId)
    }
})->get();
```

Comment: And this on my Pub Model: public function pubTapps()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tapp::class, 'pub_tapps');
    }

Comment: the problem is that it returns [ ], but when I test on MySQL that isn't the result, do you know what it could be? thanks again!!

Comment: Thanks a lot Claymore!! But still having problems when the array has more than one element [5,16] i.e. I have this: public function pubsFilteredByTapps(FilteredTappsPubsRequest $request)
    {
        $tapps_chosen = $request->get('tapps');

        $tapps_chosen = is_string($tapps_chosen) ? explode(',', str_replace('"', '', $tapps_chosen)) : $tapps_chosen;

        return Pub::whereHas('pubTapps', function ($query) use($tapps_chosen) {

            foreach ($tapps_chosen as $tappId) {
                $query->where('tapp_id', 'like', $tappId);
            }
        })->get();
    }